# why does setting an initial environment using env stall the launch of my Python script on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, shell, env

I have a test script, e.g. "test.py", and I want to make it so that it executes with a particular environment variable set before the script begins:

```
#!/usr/bin/env TEST=anything python

print "Hello, world."
```

Running this normally works as expected:

```
$ python test.py 
Hello, world.
```

However, if I run it as a program:

```
$ chmod +x test.py
$ ./test.py
```

The string is never printed, instead the execution just stalls and "top" reports a process called "test.py" which is using 100% CPU.

This only happens on my Ubuntu machine, seems to be fine on OS X.

The reason is that eventually I want to make a particular script always run in a 32-bit Python by setting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes python
```

at the top of the file.  However this is a no-go if it means the script won't execute on Linux machines.  I found there is a similar effect no matter what the specified environment variable is called.  However, if there is no environment variable set:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Hello, world."
```

The script runs just fine:

```
$ ./test.py 
Hello, world.
```

Is this a bug in Python or in `env`, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: BTW, `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` is an Apple modification to Python.  It doesn't work with other distributions of Python on OS X, for example, the official python.org OS X Pythons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux,

```
#!/usr/bin/env TEST=anything python
```

passes `TEST=anything python` as one argument to `env`.
So `env` will not process the argument properly.

The bottom line is you can only put one command after `env` on the shebang line, all else will at best be ignored.

From the [Wikipedia entry on Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability):

> Another portability problem is the interpretation of the command
>   arguments. Some systems, including Linux, [do not split up the
>   arguments[24]](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2008/11/09/msg002388.html); for example, when running the script with the first
>   line like,
>
> #!/usr/bin/env python -c
>
> That is, python -c will be passed as one argument to /usr/bin/env,
>   rather than two arguments. Cygwin also behaves this way.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the actual reason this doesn't work, Python-specifics aside.  I still don't quite understand why it seems to result in an infinite loop..

Comment: I tried it manually, running `env 'TEST=anything python' test.py`, it just results in "No such file or directory."

Comment: For an explanation about the reason for the infinite loop see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33128317/110488

Answer (score 1):

I doubt `/usr/bin/env VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes python` is going to run properly.

Instead, try setting the environment variables with Python:

```
import os

os.environ['VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT'] = 'yes'
```

Comment: That's not going to help if the goal is to launch Python in 32-bit mode.  As noted above, `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` is an Apple-supplied modification to Python.  On OS X, `/usr/bin/python` is an Apple-supplied launcher that evaluates that environment variable and a plist to determine which Python version and in what architecture to launch it.

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense. The shebang isn't of much help in that case.

Comment: Well, it *does* actually force 32-bit mode as long as `/usr/bin/python` is first on `$PATH` on OS X 10.6+ and you want to use one of the Apple-supplied Pythons. But it doesn't work with other Pythons which get installed on OS X, a common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to forget about VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT, at least on Linux.  On Mac, you could use a shell wrapper for it.

Then on Linux, you'll probably need to reinvent VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT using a small stub python script or bash script or something, hinging on something like the following:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'x86_64'
>>> platform.processor()
'x86_64'
```