# why do `#!/usr/bin/env var=val command` gets into an infinite loop

Tags: unix, scripting, env, hashbang

In `man(1) env` it say:

```
env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

So consider `print_A.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env A=b bash
echo A is $A
```

When I run it with `./print_A.sh` it hangs.

Running it with `strace ./print_A.sh` I get the following log, repeating:

```
execve("/path/to/print_A.sh", ["/path/to/print_A.sh"...], [/* 114 vars */]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="my-host", ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x504000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2a95556000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=171528, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 171528, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2a95557000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)  = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\305\30100\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1641152, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3030c00000, 2330696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3030c00000
mprotect(0x3030d30000, 1085512, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3030e2f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12f000) = 0x3030e2f000
mmap(0x3030e35000, 16456, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3030e35000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2a95581000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2a95582000
mprotect(0x3030e2f000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3030b14000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2a95581b00)   = 0
munmap(0x2a95557000, 171528)            = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x504000
brk(0x525000)                           = 0x525000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=48529088, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 48529088, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2a95583000
close(3)                                = 0
```

As commented below, running a command in a hash-bang is not equivalent to running it on the command line, but still, why does it go into an infinite loop?

Comment: Hashbang arguments are only ever split into two words, hence this is really `env A='b python2.7'`. This is, however, system-specific and has been handled differently in the past (I remember the FreeBSD commit changing this, [here is the Linux discussion](https://lkml.org/lkml/2004/2/16/74). You can achieve the same result with `#! /usr/bin/env a=b` which also (at least here) loops forever. Not quite sure yet, why that is, though.

Comment: Also: [why does setting an initial environment using env stall the launch of my Python script on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217199/why-does-setting-an-initial-environment-using-env-stall-the-launch-of-my-python), which, however, does not answer the actual question **why** that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There two parts to this answer. One has already been given in a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217199/why-does-setting-an-initial-environment-using-env-stall-the-launch-of-my-python). The answers there, however, explain the root cause for the problem, not what is actually going on.

**Part 1 - What's causing this?**

Hashbang parsing has never been really standardized. [Here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) is a very good writeup by Sven Mascheck, which also includes a table with the behavior for different operating systems.

The table shows that e.g. Linux does *all args in one*, meaning that `#!/usr/bin/env A=b bash` executes `env` with `'A=b bash'` as first argument.

**Part 2 -- Why the endless loop?**

What happens is that, `env` is executed, it sets the environment variable `A='b bash'` and then re-executes the original script. This results in the kernel re-interpreting the hashbang again and we get an endless `env`-exec loop.

After a little thinking, the problem becomes quite obvious:

A file `test.sh` with first line `#!/bin/sh param` executes `/bin/sh` as `'/bin/sh' 'param' 'test.sh'`. The script name is appended as a new command line parameter (i.e. to `argv`).

Thus in the example, `env` is actually executed as `/usr/bin/env 'A=b bash'`*`script_name`*.

`env` thus does what it's told, sets the variable, and executes *`script_name`*. This again starts hashbang interpretation and we got our loop.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a demonstration of what is going on, to supplement the accepted answer:

We can make a little executable which just shows the arguments with which it was called, and put this in the shebang line:

```
$ cat showargs.c

#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("arg %d = '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -o /tmp/showargs showargs.c

$ cat testscript
#!/tmp/showargs A=b bash
(rest of script itself ignored here)

$ chmod +x testscript 

$ ./testscript
arg 0 = '/tmp/showargs'
arg 1 = 'A=b bash'
arg 2 = './testscript'
```

Note that the `A=b bash` here is a single command-line argument.

This contrasts with:

```
$ /tmp/showargs A=b bash ./testscript 
arg 0 = '/tmp/showargs'
arg 1 = 'A=b'
arg 2 = 'bash'
arg 3 = './testscript'
```

where the command line gets tokenised by the invoking shell.

Hence with `env` in place of `showargs`, we get the infinite loop as described in the accepted answer (sets `A` to `b bash` and re-invokes the same script again).