# why does "#!/usr/bin/env PATH=... python" hang, and how else can you specify a PATH when invoking python?

Tags: python, linux, command-line-arguments, shebang

*(Asking a question in order to [answer it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), having been initially puzzled by this. Other answers obviously welcome.)*

Using `#!/usr/bin/env python` is a common trick to allow the `python` interpreter to be found using a `PATH` lookup, rather than hard-coding the path to `python`. It could be convenient to be adapt this to add a `PATH=...` argument to `env`, in order to hard-code a list of candidate directories while not hard-coding a single exact path. (This would make use of the fact that `env` uses the specified `PATH` variable when locating `python`, aside from passing it to the python process.)

For example (in `test.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env PATH=/opt/python/bin:/usr/bin:/bin python

import sys
print(sys.executable)  # show which executable it found
```

But if you try this, although the command works if executed explicitly from the shell command line:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

$ /usr/bin/env PATH=/opt/python/bin:/usr/bin:/bin python ./test.py
/opt/python/bin/python
```

it fails when trying to run it via the shebang:

```
$ ./test.py
[hangs - infinite loop]
```

Why is this, and what can be done instead?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why it fails, it turns out that this is an example of the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33126309/13596037).

As regards what can be done about it, it is possible to adapt various [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051635/13596037) to a similar problem, namely how to pass an argument to python in `#!/usr/bin/env python` (which although it is not exactly the same problem, also relates to wanting to have more than two items in the shebang line).

This gives:

```
#!/bin/sh
''''export PATH=/opt/python/bin:/usr/bin:/bin; exec python "$0" # '''

import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Invoking it via the shebang, we get:

```
$ ./test.py 
/opt/python/bin/python
```

Solutions involving `#!/usr/bin/env -S PATH=... python` (GNU coreutils >= 8.30) still appear not to be sufficiently portable (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04.4, which was the latest LTS release until April 2020, has coreutils 8.28).